# Style-based CSS selector

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to declare css path, based on style of the element?
For example, I have two ul elements on the page. One of them has style `list-style-type: lower-alpha;` :

```
<ul start="1" style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
```

and second one ul has not `list-style-type` style :

```
<ul start="1">
```

I need to apply css to the ul element, that has `list-style-type`. How to write such css selector path?

The main problem is that I have numeric ul and lower-alpha ul elements on same page and I want to make bold numbers in alpha and numeric ul's. Ie, now I use

```
.ts4page  ul,ol li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

But it makes lower-alpha ALL ul's on the page, but not only ul, that have `style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"` style.

Thank you!

Comment: Define a class in css for lower-alpha and then apply the class as css.

Comment: To define class is not good solution - I use wysiwyg editor CKEditor, that generates lists with only `style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"`

Comment: Using attribute selectors with a style attribute is not a good idea (though it might eventually end us as your only option). There are bound to be issues with extra/unexpected spaces, other properties present within the style attribute etc etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute selector `[style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"]`

```css
ul[style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul start="1" style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
</ul>
<ul start="1">
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
</ul>
```

If you have more inline style you can use `[attr*=value]` to find `list-style-type: lower-alpha;` as substring

```css
ul[style*="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul start="1" style="opacity: .7; list-style-type: lower-alpha; font-size: 12px;">
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
</ul>
<ul start="1">
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
</ul>
```